# Problems on perturbation theory with spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-spin, perturbation-theory

Problems on perturbation theory with spin (solve all perturbations up to only its first-order approximation):

1. Taking into account the relativistic correction of electron kinetic energy and spin-orbit coupling energy (H1), calculate the energy level formula of the hydrogen atom.
2. Following the above, a parallel external electric field and an external magnetic field are now added. Re-calculate the energy level formula of the hydrogen atom, assuming that the energy correction caused by the external field H2 << H1.
3. Discuss the special case of n=2.
4. If H2 roughly equals H1, discuss the energy level splitting in the case of n=2.

Comment: Are you looking for a book of worked problems or are you asking for these numbered topics to be discussed on this site ?

Comment: looks like this is not a book on perturbation theory but one on a very specific problem in perturbation theory.  Do you have an assignment due soon?

Comment: better by the end of tomorrow